# How might I be able to access a nested struct within a doubly linked list?

Tags: c++, c, struct, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to use a doubly linked list with a header struct. I believe the header struct is simply supposed to hold a count of how many structs have been created in the list, and the first and last nodes. Now I see two problems. One is connecting the header struct to the subsequent structs and the second is accessing a nested struct that i have within my list nodes (sentry). If anyone could shed some light on what I might be doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated. Code is below.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
typedef struct sentry sentry; 

struct stud{
    string name;
    char grade;
};

struct slist {
    int length;
    sentry *first;
    sentry *last;
};

struct sentry {
    slist *list;
    sentry *next;
    sentry *prev;
    stud *student;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    slist list;
    sentry *n;

    n = new sentry;

    // Full initialization of the header node.
    list.first = n;
    list.last = n;
    list.length = 0;

    n->prev = NULL;
    n->next = NULL;
    n->list = list->last;
    n->student->name = "test";
    n->student->grade = 'A';

    cout << n->student->name << '\n';
    cout << n->student->grade << '\n';

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Since `slist` already contains a pointer to an `sentry`, what stops you from using the `next` pointer on that to connect to the remaining entries?

Comment: Sorry, I should specify. The line n->list = list-> last; Gives me an error over incompatible types. And i think either the assignment to name and grade cause the program to crash or the output causes it.

Comment: Inside your sentry, you're never instantiating **stud** using dynamic memory.  In your main function, before:
n->student->name = "test";
n->student->grade = 'A';

You must say **n->student = new stud;**
Then you can have the two following statements assigning a name and a grade.

Comment: @SantiagoVarela Thank you very much. First time using pointers actually so I thought that invoking a new sentry would consequentially create new stud.

Comment: @GabeClark Unfortunately it doesn't :/ . In C++ you have to make everything explicit and you have to do it yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you modify your struct sentry to not include `slist *list`?
Why is having a **2-way relationship** between `sentry` and `slist` **necessary**? It makes it tedious to maintain, to read and update the values inside the list of the sentry. Nevermind, deallocating the memory on the heap to avoid **memory leaks**. Why  not have `slist` (the header) only have information about the `sentry`. In this way you remove the complexity of a double binding between `sentry` and `slist`.

```
 struct sentry {
        sentry *next;
        sentry *prev;
        stud *student;
 };
```

Comment: The struct prototypes were given to us by our professor. I personally created a DLL without the header struct and found that must easier to abstract and manage than a DLL containing the header struct. I think I will give it a shot without the 2 way relationship because as you said, it is tedious. This way, to my understanding, the header simply acts as a sandwich containing the two ends of the DLL.

Comment: @GabeClark, could you mark the answer as correct one, if it indeed really help you?

Comment: You got it! I can now access each of my three structs:D